# how many ways can we get data from webservice?

Tags: iphone

i know using xml parser ....

Is any another way we can get the data from web service.

if it is there please send links or example's or any documents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

json is a good choice; http://github.com/stig/json-framework

Answer (score 0):

I started from this well explained [tutorial](http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/43209/1954?pf=true)